# Can not get header token in middleware

Tags: express

When I sign up a user, the header gets set in the `/signup` route.
[Header token set successfully](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YVE7N.png)

But when I try to access the header on `/` route. The authorization fails because in auth.js, getting the header with `const token = req.header('curToken')` returns `undefined`. In the network log I can see that the header that has been set (`curToken`) is empty or non-existent, but is allowed.  [Can not get Header token](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jvSB7.jpg)

```js
// index.js
const express = require('express')
require('./db/mongoose')
const userRouter = require('./routers/user')

const app = express()
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000
const cors = require('cors')

app.options('*', cors())
app.use(cors())

app.use(express.json())
app.use(userRouter)

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Server is running on port ${port}`)
})

// user.js (express route)
const express = require('express')
const User = require('../models/user')
const auth = require('../middleware/auth')
const router = new express.Router()

// signup
router.post('/signup', async (req, res) => {
    const user = new User(req.body)
    
    try {   
        await user.save()
        const token = await user.generateAuthToken()
        res.set('curToken', token) // set header

        console.log('registered')
        res.send({ user, token })
    } catch(err) {
        res.status(400).send(err)
    }

})

// test if token header is accesible
router.get('', auth, async (req, res) => {
    try {
        // const users = await User.find({})
        res.send("logged in.")
    } catch(err) {
        res.send(err)
    }
})


module.exports = router

// auth.js middleware
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken')
const User = require('../models/user')

const auth = async (req, res, next) => {
    res.header('Access-Control-Expose-Headers', 'curToken')
    try {
        const token = req.header('curToken') // get header
        console.log('auth token:', token) // header returns undefined
        const decoded = jwt.verify(token, 'thisismysecretcode')
        const user = await User.findOne({ _id: decoded._id, 'tokens.token': token })
        
        if (!user) {
            throw new Error()
        }

        req.token = token
        req.user = user
        next()
    } catch(err) {
        res.status(401).send({error: 'Please authenticate.'})
    }
}

module.exports = auth
```

```js
// Sign Up
<template>
<div>
  SignUp
  <form @submit="sendRegData" @submit.prevent>
      <input type="text" v-model="firstName" name="firstName" placeholder="First name"><br>
      <input type="text" v-model="lastName" name="lastName" placeholder="Last name"><br>
      <input type="text" v-model="email" name="email" placeholder="Email"><br>
      <input type="text" v-model="password" name="password" placeholder="Password"><br>
      <input type="submit" value="Send">
    </form>
</div>
</template> 

<script>
import axios from 'axios';

export default {
  name: "SignUp",
  data() {
    return {
      firstName: null,
      lastName: null,
      email: null,
      password: null
    }
  }, 
  methods: {
    async sendRegData() {
      try {
        await axios.post('http://localhost:3000/signup', {
            firstName: this.firstName,
            lastName: this.lastName,
            email: this.email,
            password: this.password
        }).then((res) => {
            let token = res.data.token
            // console.log('token res received in front:', token)
            // localStorage.setItem("currentToken", token)
            // console.log('curToken:', localStorage.getItem("currentToken"))
        })   
      } catch(err) {
        console.log(err)
      }
    }
  }
};
</script>

// login
<template>
  <div class="home">
    <!-- <h1>{{ User.firstName }}</h1> -->
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import axios from 'axios';

export default {
  name: "Page",
  
  data() {
    return {
      Users: {},
      dataFetched: false
    }
  },
  async mounted() {
    try {
      this.Users = await axios.get('http://localhost:3000/')
      console.log(this.Users)
      // this.User = this.User.data[0] // transform first object from array
      // this.dataFetched = true
    } catch(err) {
        console.error(err)
    }
    
  }
};
</script>
```

Comment: You need to show us the code which posts to login and how you handle the header response, setting the token into storage and how you load it to send for next request etc, as simply setting a response header won't magically tell the client to send it up on subsequent requests and we cant tell from the code provided if you are indeed sending it.

Comment: @LawrenceCherone That's all the code I have when it comes to express, excluding the database setup. I thought to set the header would make it available cross domain. I'm not sure how to pass it onto login, that's my issue then.

Comment: Yep, the res.set will set the response header, the client then needs to parse that and collect/store the value (cookie/local storage), and then use it in subsequent requests, so its the client side code we need to see.

Comment: I have added the SignUp and Page (which is basically the login page) below the Express code. I'm using Vue for the front. All I do in Page.vue is get some data from the db using axios.

I also have a Github where I always keep my files: https://github.com/MacintoshSpock/application